# How to quit the app when the main window is closed

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

My macOS app was rejected because "closing the main window does not quit the app."

I have implemented the

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

method in my app delegate and it seems to close the app, so I'm not sure why it was rejected.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Close all open windows, obviously.

Comment: @user11707424 are you check my answeer

Answer (score 3):

You must call terminate NSApplication:

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
    return true
}
```